# google website Language Translator for website

Tags: javascript, google-translate

I am using the google website translator. It's working lovely. The problem is the user click the language button it will display the header [Mywebsite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrPbf.jpg) it will mess up with my navbar. If close the header chosen language is not displayed it will automatically translate into original language.

My Script is

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

May be there is something wrong with your site css, Because when I add google translater it automatically adjust the header. Have a look at this image.
[image: Image with google translater]

Comment: please specify what type of mistake in my css.

Comment: @Macroid how, when we didn’t even get to see your site and what coding it uses, but only a mere screenshot …? Please go read [ask], and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: First of all I used term 'may be' its css problem, as of now I cant see your site, how can I comment what type of mistake is there. According to my knowledge when we add google translator it automatically set the position.

Comment: I am fresher to coding .now i understand how to ask Question. Thank u.